# I'm getting issue with updating real DOM when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below Code does'nt work

I'm getting issue with updating real DOM when updating state.

```
handleAllCheckBoxChange(selectedRows) {
 this.setState({
  isLoading: true,
}, () => {
     this.props.getSelectedRow(selectedRows); // This takes 600ms to complete.
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
        }); 
  }
};
```

///And if i use this.....

```
handleSelectRows() {
  this.props.getSelectedRow(this.state.selectedRows);
   this.setState({
   isLoading: true,
  });
}

handleAllCheckBoxChange(selectedRows) {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: true,
  });
  setTimeout(this.handleSelectRows, 50);
}
```

this works fine

Comment: I would stick with the second one anyways. The first one seems like some dangerous use of setState() that could lead to issues. Which it seems like you are experiencing.

Comment: I notice that you're never setting isLoading to false in your second example.

Comment: It was just a typo, the actual problem i face here is the time taken to perform js program -> ""this.props.getSelectedRow(selectedRows)"".  while when i use a setTimeout it works fine as the real gets updated. 

Is it a good practice to use setTimeOut to solve this type of issue.